# How to add and remove a class in a loop with jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

A simple loop is what I am looking for, I have a button and all that's needed is a simple loop to add and remove a class to an element.

```
    <div id="button" class="animate">

    </div>
```

What I want to do is loop over 3 times and add and remove a class to the #button.

So initially when the screen loads it will render as above, after 2 seconds the animate class will be removed then after 2 more seconds the 'animate' class is added, then removed and this loops for x amount of times.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loops = 3 * 2;
    function removeAddClass() {
        $("#button").toggleClass("animate");
        if (--loops > 0)
             setTimeout(removeAddClass, 2000);
    }
    removeAddClass();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/26GUe/

Comment: You're welcome. In case it's not obvious, if you need to add a delay before the first toggle of the class just change the last line `removeAddClass()` to be `setTimeout(removeAddClass, 2000)`.

Answer (score 3):

```js
//Create a var to store the index of red element
var count = -1;
function AddRedClass() {
  var boxes = $('.box');
  var boxLength = boxes.length - 1;
  //Check if the actual item isn't more than the length then add 1 otherway restart to 0
  count < boxLength ? count++ : count=0;
  //Remove the class and add it to the new target
  boxes.removeClass('red').eq(count).addClass('red');
}
setInterval(AddRedClass, 1000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
}
.box {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  transition: background .3s linear;
}
.red {
  background: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    c-1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-4
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-5
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-6
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-7
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-8
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    c-9
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might help.

```
for (var i=0;i<x;i++)
{ 
$("#button").removeClass("animate").delay(2000).addClass("animate").delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: But `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` won't go in the animation queue will they?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can do this.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function(){ 
            if(jQuery('#button').hasClass('animate')) {
                jQuery('#button').removeClass('animate')
            }
            else{
                jQuery('#button').addClass('animate')
            }
            },2000);
    });
</script>
<div id="button" class="animate"></div>
```

Hope will help!

Comment: This will create an infinite loop, the question asks for **3** changes.

Comment: This infinite loop is good if i want it to go on and on. Thanks anyway the answer below does the trick nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){
  var currentclass=$('.button').attr('class');

  if(currentclass=="animate"){
    $('#button').removeClass("animate");      
  } else {
    $('#button').addClass("animate");
  }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Included within `$(document).ready(function() {` the following JQuery will work:

```
function loopAnimate() {
    var $btn = $("#button"),
        changes = $btn.data("changes") || 0;

    $btn.delay(2000).queue(function (next) {           
        $btn.toggleClass("animate");       
        next();        
        if (changes <= 3) {
            $btn.data("changes", changes + 1);
            loopAnimate();
        }
    });
}

loopAnimate();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex8B2/2/)

Edit: updated to include the suggested modifications by @nnnnnn

Comment: `changes = $btn.attr("data-changes") || 0;` is a more compact way of defaulting to 0 if the attribute has not been set, with the added benefit that it doesn't call `.attr()` twice. If you use `.data("changes")` instead of `.attr("data-changes")` you wouldn't have to worry about using `parseInt()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn nice, I didn't know about `$btn.attr("data-changes") || 0;`